# What do you call the white cloth fabric used on tables and curtains?

Tags: word-request

Is there a single word for it? I am trying to think of a word that includes both, but aside cloth I can't think of any. There has to be a more specific word for cloth used for non-clothing stuffs like curtains and tabletop.

Comment: Linen? Damask? Fabric is named for its weave rather than its colour.

Comment: Often, the fabric for curtains and upholstery material are slightly different. Though both could be made of cotton or silk....for example.

Comment: 'Furnishing fabrics'?

Answer (score 1):

As a dressmaker, in Brit english there isn't a word for your description, as somebody said there is Linen but that also included bed linen, but doesn't cover curtains as curtains are rarely made from linen.

> Linen (/ˈlɪnən/) is a textile made from the fibers of the flax plant.
> Linen is very strong, absorbent, and dries faster than cotton. ...
> [Linen on wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linen)

Especially as the fabric used for curtains is also used for upholstery because tablecloth fabric is much finer, more like a bedding quality fabric.

Comment: And muslin too.

Comment: muslin is a very loose weave not used for either of these purposes

Answer (score 0):

"A cloth that's used in both tablecloths and curtains" doesn't exactly narrow it down uniquely, but you may be thinking of linen.

Comment: Linen is, however, a fairly common fabric used for clothing.